# Pegar conteúdo de e-mail resposta

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap, nodemailer

Estou utilizando a biblioteca do [imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) para entrar em uma conta da empresa e trazer os novos emails, quando é uma resposta de um e-mail gostaria de pegar apenas o conteúdo novo mas não consigo isso apenas a conversa completa. Vou dar um exemplo:

Um cliente me manda um e-mail com o seguinte conteúdo: 'Oi'

Eu respondo dizendo: 'Oi tudo bem ?'

Ele me responde: 'Tudo ótimo'

Quando eu for verificar minha caixa de e-mail pelo node para salvar os texto. quero pegar apenas o ultimo conteúdo que ele me mandou que seria 'Tudo ótimo', mas a biblioteca do `imap` me retorna a conversa inteira assim:

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:teste

5 de Abril de 2018 10:31, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu:
resposta cliente

5 de Abril de 2018 10:30, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:resposta atendimento

5 de Abril de 2018 09:45, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu:
email enviado pelo cliente

---

Neste exemplo do log gostaria de pegar apenas o lorem ipsum... que é o conteúdo do ultimo e-mail resposta.

Meu código:

```
imap.once('ready', function () {
    openInbox(imap, function (err, box) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:9999', {
            bodies: [''],
            struct: true
        });
        f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
            msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
                var buffer = '';
                var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
                stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                });

                stream.once('end', function () {
                    simpleParser(buffer).then(function(mail){
                        var email = {};
                        if (mail.headers.has('date')) {
                            email.date = (mail.headers.get('date'));
                        }
                        if (mail.headers.has('subject')) {
                            email.subject = (mail.headers.get('subject'));
                        }
                        if (mail.headers.has('from')) {
                            email.address = (mail.headers.get('from').value[0].address);
                        }

                        if (mail.inReplyTo) {
                            console.log(mail.text);
                            console.log('----');

                        } else {
                            email.text = mail.text;
                        }
                        // console.log(email);


                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                });
            });
            msg.once('attributes', function (attrs) {
                // console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
            });
            msg.once('end', function () {
                // console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
            });
        });
        f.once('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
        });
        f.once('end', function () {
            console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
            return imap.end();
        });
    });
});

imap.once('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', function () {
    console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

Se alguém pudesse me dar alguma ajuda ficarei muito grato. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O cliente de email vai criando uma conversa, com o que vc envia e o que recebe, ok. Vc quer pegar apenas a última resposta recebida ou a última mensagem, mesmo que seja a sua, que vc enviou?

Comment: A ultima mensagem que o cliente me enviou, ou seja a última resposta recebida

Comment: Pode mostrar como ficaria uma conversa no padrão Gmail? Pode criar um JSFiddle apenas com o texto da conversa (claro, substituindo os textos originais por _lorem ipsum_ ou qualquer texto de exemplo)

Comment: [link para documento de texto](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Amu4kYMSj_mVh7s13A5sd7zRp6WvbA) .Coloquei nesse documento um exemplo de como fica o `console.log(mail.text)` de uma conversa do Gmail. O conteúdo é irrelevante é apenas copia de um texto promocional que recebi, e usei apenas para teste, o importante seria pegar esse conteúdo.

Comment: Cara, é complicado fazer isso porque os padrões podem ser diferentes de um cliente de email para outro. O interessante seria verificar os padrões dos clientes de mail que vc mais trabalha e ir ajustando o código que postei para que abranja todos ao máximo possível. Vejo que esta é a única forma de resolver a questão. Se quiser posso criar um chat aqui para a gente poder trabalhar em cima disso, de modo a chegar em um código o mais próximo do 100%, se o código da minha resposta já não possa ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o mesmo exemplo do [@DiegoMarques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/87837/diego-marques)

```
/^(Em\s)?\d{1,2} de \w+ de \d{4}/gm
```

A expressão acima irá separar se encontrar as seguintes sequencias: *5 de Abril de 2018* e ou *Em 10 de abril de 2018*

A expressão abaixo é mais completa:

```
^(Em\s)?\d{1,2}\sde\s\w+\sde\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([^@]+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+|,\s\sescreveu\:)?
```

e irá separar se encontrar as seguintes sequencias:

```
5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br
Em 5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br

10 de abril de 2018 09:49
10 de abril de 2018 09:49,  escreveu:
Em 10 de abril de 2018 09:49
Em 10 de abril de 2018 09:49,  escreveu:
```

> Podes testar em [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/d6EEw7/1)

No caso do *Outlook*, a data vem com o padrão:

```
Em qua, 11 de abr de 2018 às 09:08
```

Expressão fica assim:

```
^(Em\s\w+,\s)|(Em\s)?\d{1,2}\sde\s\w+\sde\s\d{4}\s(às\s)?\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([^@]+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+|,\s\sescreveu\:)?
```

Ou modo simples:

```
/^(Em\s\w+,\s)|(Em\s)?\d{1,2} de \w+ de \d{4}/gm
```

> Podes testar em [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TEmSfl/1/)

#### Exemplo 1

```js
let mail = {
   text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:teste

5 de Abril de 2018 10:31, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: resposta cliente

5 de Abril de 2018 10:30, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:resposta atendimento

5 de Abril de 2018 09:45, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: email enviado pelo cliente`
}

let reg = /^(Em\s)?\d{1,2} de \w+ de \d{4}/gm,
    separa = mail.text.split(reg);
console.log(separa[0]);
```

#### Exemplo 2

```js
let mail = {
   text: `Olá, como vai?

Se você é programador ou desenvolvedor de diversos tipos de aplicações C#
(web, desktop, mobile, etc.), então este lançamento é pra você:



Ao final deste curso você irá tirar proveito das melhorias de parâmetros
out e in, aprender a retornar múltiplos valores de forma simples com
tuplas, simplificar condições e conversões de valores com correspondência
de padrões, explorar funções locais e nova sintaxe de expressão no C# 7,
padronizar os estilos de código C# da sua equipe de desenvolvimento e muito
mais!
Comece já ️

Mais lançamentos ✨

*AspNet Identity*
Parte 1: Gerencie contas de usuários

Parte 2: Autenticação, segurança com lockout e "Esqueci a senha"

Parte 3: Autorização, autenticação externa com redes sociais

Parte 4: Autenticação mais segura com 2 fatores


*Lean Inbound*
Parte 1: Fundamentos de Marketing e Vendas para Novos Negócios

Parte 2: Práticas de Validação, Marketing e Vendas

*Recycler
View*
Parte 1:
Listas
flexíveis e performáticas



*Google Charts*Criando e customizando gráficos para a web


*DNS*
Entenda a resolução de nomes na internet


*Asp.NET Core*
Uma webapp usando o padrão MVC


*Final
Cut*
Introdução a Edição de Vídeos



Em 10 de abril de 2018 09:49,  escreveu:

> Resposta atendimento
>
>
> 10 de Abril de 2018 09:48, "erick zanetti"  > escreveu:
>
>
> Olá, erick,
> A data de entrega do seu trabalho Lista Vetores
>  é
> amanhã. Você deseja entregá-lo?
>
>
> Lista Vetores
> Prazo: 7 de abr
> ABRIR
>
> Se você não quiser receber e-mails do Sala de aula, cancele sua inscrição
> .
>
>
>`
}
let reg = /^(Em\s)?\d{1,2} de \w+ de \d{4}/gm,
    separa = mail.text.split(reg);
console.log(separa[0]);
```

Comment: Emails da Microsoft (Outlook ou Hotmail) isso não vai funcionar, é ate mais fácil precisa apenas de `mail.text.split(/______________________________/g);`. Com todas as resposta que tive consegui fazer o que queria e deixar tudo muito bem validado, Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Tente assim veja se funciona com o Outlook: `^(Em\s\w+,\s)|(Em\s)?\d{1,2}\sde\s\w+\sde\s\d{4}\s(às\s)?\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([^@]+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+|,\s\sescreveu\:)?` .... eu fiz o teste com meus email veja o regex funcionando: https://regex101.com/r/TEmSfl/1

Answer (score 2):

O problema neste caso é que as respostas realmente são concatenadas com a mensagem, e quem faz isso é o cliente de e-mail do usuário que está respondendo.

O que você pode fazer neste caso é tratar o texto todo como uma string e filtrar o conteúdo desejado. O que pode te ajudar neste caso são expressões regulares, que te ajudará a limpar o texto indesejado através de padrões.

Neste exemplo que você postou, dá para perceber o seguinte padrão quando são concatenadas as outras respostas:

```
<dia> de <mês> de <ano> <hora>:<minuto>, <email> (mailto:<email>) escreveu:
```

Então segue um exemplo em javascript extraindo o conteúdo baseado em seu exemplo:

```
var msg = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."' +
'' +
'5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:teste' +
'' +
'5 de Abril de 2018 10:31, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: resposta cliente' +
'' +
'5 de Abril de 2018 10:30, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:resposta atendimento' +
'' +
'5 de Abril de 2018 09:45, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: email enviado pelo cliente';

var arrMsg = msg.split(/[0-9]+ de [a-zA-Z]+ de [0-9]+ [0-9:]+, [^@]+@[^ ]+ \(mailto:[^@]+@[^ ]+\) escreveu:/g);

var msgTratada = arrMsg[0];

console.log(msgTratada);
```

Lembrando que se o padrão mudar, você terá que adaptar o tratamento para cobrir essas variações.

Comment: Muito bom, isso realmente vai funcionar nesse caso, o problema é que para cada gerenciador de e-mail origem vai ser um padrão diferente, Gmail, Outlook, Webmail (que foi o utilizado para esse exemplo), entre outros.

Answer (score 2):

Como seu último *reply* ou mensagem enviada sempre apresenta uma linha com um horário no formato `hh:mm`, a forma que fiz foi detectar em que linha da conversa existe strings com essa informação.

O que fiz foi quebrar toda a conversa em array (`msg_`) separando por quebra de linha `\n`. Em seguida um `for` percorrendo a array verificando quais índices possuem `hh:mm` com a regex `/\d+:\d+/` (números próximos antes e depois de dois pontos `:`), e armazenando o *índice* e o *texto* das ocorrências em um objeto (`data_obj = {}`).

> O que preciso saber é em qual linha possui `hh:mm`, e verificar se
>   nessa linha também possui uma data no formato "*dia* **de** *mês* **de
>   20**".

Supondo este exemplo de conversa:

```
> Tudo bem! Estarei lá às 8:30
> 5 de Abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:teste
> 5 de Abril de 2018 10:31, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: resposta cliente
```

No caso acima, o que interessa é pegar apenas o texto "*> Tudo bem! Estarei lá às 8:30*", que é a última conversa recebida.

No primeiro `for`, verificando `hh:mm`, irá gerar o objeto:

```
data_obj = {
0: "> tudo bem! estarei lá às 8:30",
1: "> 5 de abril de 2018 10:50, atendimento@teste.com.br (mailto:atendimento@teste.com.br) escreveu:teste",
2: "> 5 de abril de 2018 10:31, erickzanetti@teste.net.br (mailto:erickzanetti@teste.net.br) escreveu: resposta cliente"
}
```

Em todas as linhas foram encontrados o padrão `hh:mm` e adicionados ao objeto, sendo a *chave* a posição da ocorrência na array inicialmente criada; e o valor da respectiva *chave* o texto (convertido para *lowercase* para melhor verificação posterior). Mas veja que o primeiro item do objeto, embora possui um horário (`8:30`) não possui uma data (no segundo `for` que virá, esse item será ignorado).

Com o objeto alimentado, irei fazer um `for in` verificando se em cada texto do objeto possui o padrão "*dia* **de** *mês* **de 20**" com a regex:

```
/\d\sde\s(jan|fev|mar|abr|mai|jun|jul|ago|set|out|nov|dez)[\w]+\sde\s20/
```

> **Nota:** a regex acima só irá funcionar até o ano 2099. :D

A primeira ocorrência que for encontrada, a sua *chave* será a posição da array inicial (`msg_`) que é até onde eu quero pegar as informações. Neste caso, eu faço um `join` com `\n` (quebra de linha) e `slice(0, nome_da_chave_encontrada)`.

A parte teórica às vezes é um pouco difícil de entender e de explicar, mas vendo o código fica mais claro.

**Veja o exemplo:**

O texto da conversa do exemplo abaixo é este:

```
Olá, como vai?
Se você é programador ou desenvolvedor de diversos tipos de aplicações C#
(web, desktop, mobile, etc.), então este lançamento é pra você:
Ao final deste curso você irá tirar proveito das melhorias de parâmetros
out e in, aprender a retornar múltiplos valores de forma simples com
tuplas, simplificar condições e conversões de valores com correspondência
de padrões, explorar funções locais e nova sintaxe de expressão no C# 7,
padronizar os estilos de código C# da sua equipe de desenvolvimento e muito
mais!
Comece já
Em 10 de abril de 2018 09:49,  escreveu:
> Resposta atendimento
>
>
> 10 de Abril de 2018 09:48, "erick zanetti"  > escreveu:
>
>
> Olá, erick,
> A data de entrega do seu trabalho Lista Vetores
>  é
> amanhã. Você deseja entregá-lo?
```

**Obs.:** No código do exemplo, adicionei `\n` apenas para simular quebras de linha.

```js
var mail = {
   "text":
   'Olá, como vai?\n\n'
   +'Se você é programador ou desenvolvedor de diversos tipos de aplicações C#\n'
   +'(web, desktop, mobile, etc.), então este lançamento é pra você:\n\n\n'
   +'Ao final deste curso você irá tirar proveito das melhorias de parâmetros\n'
   +'out e in, aprender a retornar múltiplos valores de forma simples com\n'
   +'tuplas, simplificar condições e conversões de valores com correspondência\n'
   +'de padrões, explorar funções locais e nova sintaxe de expressão no C# 7,\n'
   +'padronizar os estilos de código C# da sua equipe de desenvolvimento e muito\n'
   +'mais!\n'
   +'Comece já\n\n'
   +'Em 10 de abril de 2018 09:49,  escreveu:\n\n'
   +'> Resposta atendimento\n'
   +'>\n'
   +'>\n'
   +'> 10 de Abril de 2018 09:48, "erick zanetti"  > escreveu:\n'
   +'>\n'
   +'>\n'
   +'> Olá, erick,\n'
   +'> A data de entrega do seu trabalho Lista Vetores\n'
   +'>  é\n'
   +'> amanhã. Você deseja entregá-lo?'
}

msg_ = mail.text.split("\n");

var idx_;
var data_obj = {};
for(var x=0; x<msg_.length; x++){
   if(msg_[x].match(/\d+:\d+/)){
      data_obj[x] = msg_[x].toLowerCase();
   }
}

for(var key in data_obj){
   if(data_obj[key].match(/\d\sde\s(jan|fev|mar|abr|mai|jun|jul|ago|set|out|nov|dez)[\w]+\sde\s20/)){
      idx_ = key;
      break;
   }
}

var ultima = msg_.slice(0,idx_).join("\n");

console.log(ultima);
```